# Differences between Stateful session bean and POJO linked in a SessionScoped ManagedBean

Tags: jakarta-ee, pojo, managed-bean, stateful-session-bean

I'm quite new to Java EE and I was asking myself the following question:

What are the differences between holding a link to a Stateful session bean and holding a link to a POJO in a SessionScoped Managed bean?

Since the ManagedBean is sessionscoped it's kept during the Session. Therefore I was thinking I could still have access to a simple POJO during the session. Right?

So what's the real purpose of a SFSB here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFSB is an EJB and therefore has support for things like Container Managed Transactions, @Asynchronous method invocation and the @Schedule and @Timeout among other things.

The managed Bean has access to things like FacesContext and HttpContext etc..

So depending on your needs, the SFSB might not add anything you need. I for example have written a few hundred SLSB but not yet created my first SFSB, Because I let the User sessions live in the ManagedBeans and let the ejb-tier be user-session-unaware.

Look at: [sessionscoped managed bean vs stateful ejb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842066/sessionscoped-managed-bean-vs-stateful-ejb)